# Inner Product on Division Algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28real_division_algebras%29), Wikipedia gives a proof that the only finite dimensional associative division algebras over $\mathbb{R}$ are $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}, \mathbb{H}$.

The proof proceeds by taking such a division algebra $D$, observing that multiplication by  $d \in D$ gives an endomorphism of $D$ which can be represented by a matrix corresponding to $d$. Then, we consider $V \subset D$, the subspace of $D$ corresponding to matrices with trace $0$. At some point, an inner product of $V$ given by $\langle a, b \rangle=-ab-ba$ appears. At my current understanding (undergraduate mathematics) this inner product seems mysterious. I can prove that it works but I don't understand why that is a natural choice. Can someone give me some insight?

Edit. Is there maybe a way to think about this result using Lie Theory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional division algebra over $\mathbb R$. The set $A'$ of all $u\in A$ s.t. $u^2\leq 0$ is a subspace in $A$. The proof needs some computations. What we can write is that

$$u^2=-Q(u)\leq 0,$$

for all $u\in A'$, with $Q(u)\in\mathbb R$ s.t. $Q(u)\geq 0$. Moreover, as $A$ is a division algebra

$$u=0\Leftrightarrow Q(u)=0,$$

and $Q(au)=a^2Q(u)$. The symmetric bilinear form $B(u,v)$ in the OP is deduced from $Q(u)$ as follows:

$$B(u,v):=Q(u+v)-Q(u)-Q(v)=-(uv+vu).$$

And now? You can use $B(u,v)$ to deduce the existence of an orthonormal base of the subspace of $A$ which generates it as an algebra. This is the point of view considered in Wikipedia's proof. One works on the (finite) dimension of $A$ to classify finite dim. division algebras, arriving at the result.

Comment: I guess I am curious as to why this approach is a natural one. To me, the trace map is very natural and so it makes sense to think about the kernel (which is why I phrased the question in that way!). But then we get this bilinear form. Does this have any relation to the trace map? Could one have expected such a form to exist? In your explanation you seem to start by defining a particular map $Q$. Given such a $Q$, can one always find a bilinear form? Why do you pick the $Q$ in that way?

Comment: The trace is surely something natural and useful, but then the classification goes on using the bilinear form: one uses it to define an orthonormal basis. I do not see the 2 objects in contrast: in Wiki's proof it is stated that $A'$ is the subspace of all $u$ s.t. $\operatorname{tr} u=0$.