# Show that we have an inner product (in division algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reading the Wikipedia proof of the Frobenius theorem and encountered an akward inner product. We are looking at a division algebra $D$ over $\mathbb{R}$. We have shown that $V=\{a\in D\mid a^2\leq 0\}$ is a linear subspace of $D$. Now they define this inner product on $V$: $$\left<a,b\right>=-(ab+ba).$$ Now the only thing that I don't fully understand is: "Why is this positive?" They are using as an argument that $ab+ba=(a+b)^2-a^2-b^2$ and all the terms in the RHS are negative because they lie in $V$. I'm however not able to convince myself that this whole expression is negative. For instance: Why can't we find $a,b\in V$ for wich $(a+b)^2>a^2+b^2$. I feel like I'm missing something really simple.

**N.B.**  This would seem like a question similar to [Help with proof of Frobenius Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/549480/145141) and/or [Inner Product on Division Algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/476682/145141), but I'm still not fully convinced that we actually have an inner product. (I.e. why is it positive?)

Comment: this seems to be the anticommuator for a complex innerproduct restricted to imaginary values (so that the conjugate value is equal to the negative of the value and the square is less than 0.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity $ab+ba = (a+b)^2 - a^2 - b^2$ shows that $\langle a,b\rangle$ is real, so that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is indeed a bilinear form. The symmetry follows from the commutativity of addition.

For the positive definiteness, one considers the case where both arguments are the same, but

$$\langle a,a\rangle = - (aa+aa) = -2a^2$$

is non-negative by the definition of $V$ as the subspace where $x^2\leqslant 0$, and since $D$ is a division algebra, we have $-2a^2 = 0$ only for $a = 0$, so $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is positive definite.

Comment: How silly of me. I tried to prove that it's positive for arbitraty $a$ and $b$, wich is of course not necessary. Thanks anyway.